# "That" as an adverb in negative sentence

Tags: adverbs

Is it right to use "that" in front of adjectives such as "much" or "many" as an adverb in negative or interrogative sentences?:

-I don't have *that much* money.

-Do you really have *that many* friends?

Which one is correct? Do I need to modify any of these sentences?

Comment: They're both fine. And they could both be used with either of two "nuances". Sometimes, ***that*** contextually refers to some *specific* amount of money / number of friends that's already been mentioned - in which case it's more likely to be heavily stressed in speech, but this isn't always the case. Other times (less likely to be stressed), it doesn't refer to any particular amount - you could think of it as meaning *[not] as much as you might have thought*, or *[not] as much as the **average** person has*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usage is correct in both examples.

*That* can be interchanged with *so* without loss of understanding

> I don't have *so* much money.
>   Do you really have *so* many friends?

without additional context, usually using *that* implies a large amount as in *a lot of*.

> I don't have *a lot of* money.
>   Do you really have *a lot of* friends?

The opposite would be

> so much <> so little
>   so many <> so few